# Converting Cast syntax from PostgreSQL to Hive

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive

The following syntax is from a larger Vertica query (postgreSQL). Is it possible to transform this syntax into Hive? Operators are consistent. If so, how?

**Current Error is: 
FAILED: ParseException line 22:19 cannot recognize input near '|' 'CAST' '(' in expression specification**

```
 ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((' || 
    CAST(TRUNC(request_lng / {{zoom_factor}},2) AS numeric) * {{zoom_factor}} + sign(request_lng)*(.01 * {{zoom_factor}})
    || ' ' ||
    CAST(TRUNC(request_lat / ({{zoom_factor}} * {{stretch_factor}}),2) AS numeric) * ({{zoom_factor}}*{{stretch_factor}}) + sign(request_lat)*(.01 * {{zoom_factor}} * {{stretch_factor}})
    || ', ' ||
    CAST(TRUNC(request_lng / {{zoom_factor}},2) AS numeric) * {{zoom_factor}} + sign(request_lng)*(.01 * {{zoom_factor}})
    || ' ' ||
    CAST(TRUNC(request_lat / ({{zoom_factor}} * {{stretch_factor}}),2) AS numeric) * ({{zoom_factor}}*{{stretch_factor}}) 
    || ', ' ||
    CAST(TRUNC(request_lng / {{zoom_factor}},2) AS numeric) * {{zoom_factor}}  
    || ' ' ||
    CAST(TRUNC(request_lat / ({{zoom_factor}} * {{stretch_factor}}),2) AS numeric) * ({{zoom_factor}}*{{stretch_factor}}) 
    || ', ' ||
    CAST(TRUNC(request_lng / {{zoom_factor}},2) AS numeric) * {{zoom_factor}}  
    || ' ' ||
    CAST(TRUNC(request_lat / ({{zoom_factor}} * {{stretch_factor}}),2) AS numeric) * ({{zoom_factor}}*{{stretch_factor}}) + sign(request_lat)*(.01 * {{zoom_factor}} * {{stretch_factor}})
    || ', ' ||
    CAST(TRUNC(request_lng / {{zoom_factor}},2) AS numeric) * {{zoom_factor}} + sign(request_lng)*(.01 * {{zoom_factor}})
    || ' ' ||
    CAST(TRUNC(request_lat / ({{zoom_factor}} * {{stretch_factor}}),2) AS numeric) * ({{zoom_factor}}*{{stretch_factor}}) + sign(request_lat)*(.01 * {{zoom_factor}} * {{stretch_factor}})
    ||'))') as geography
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point, Hive does not support spatial queries.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5168
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Spatial+queries (design docs)